# solving a quadratic with tensor coefficients

Tags: quadratics, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, newton-raphson, quadratic-programming

Given the equation
$Att^T+Bt+C=0$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A,B$ are symmetric, can it be solved for $t \in \mathbb{C}^{m}$ in a closed-form fashion via some variant of the quadratic formula? This comes from an attempt at using a 3rd-order Newton optimization step.

Following the traditional quadratic formula approach, you end up needing the square root of $\frac{1}{4}A^{-1}BA^{-1}B-A^{-1}C$. It's not obvious to me that this value is symmetric; maybe it is. I've read some good ideas for computing the square root of symmetric matrices. Even if the square root was not exact, meaning I had two roots that are approximately equal, that would still be interesting.

Comment: Why $tt^T$ instead of $tt$ ?

Comment: If I am right, the equation describes the intersection of $m$ hyperquadrics, which can consist of $2^m$ points. There cannot be a closed-form solution, as that would imply a closed-form for the roots of polynomials of that degree.

Comment: $tt^T$ (aka, m x m) should be the necessary shape for producing a single-dimension result against $A$.

Comment: This is matrix notation, not tensor. Anyway, ponder my second comment.